# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object'

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have 3 dropdownlist 2 with same source, 3rd with selected list. and if selected list not null I should remove selecteds from first one, and bind in 3rd one. second is static that shows orginal list.

but I couldn't figure out how to foreach in an object.

> ERROR : foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object'
>   because 'object' does not contain a public definition for
>   'GetEnumerator'

```
    public void DataSource(object source, object select, string Value = "UId", string Text = "Text")
    {
        ddlThis.DataSource = source;
        ddlThis.DataTextField = Text;
        ddlThis.DataValueField = Value;
        ddlThis.DataBind();

        ddlThisHidden.DataSource = source;
        ddlThisHidden.DataTextField = Text;
        ddlThisHidden.DataValueField = Value;
        ddlThisHidden.DataBind();

        if (select != null)
        {
            ddlOther.DataSource = select;
            ddlOther.DataTextField = Text;
            ddlOther.DataValueField = Value;
            ddlOther.DataBind();

            foreach (var item in ddlOther.DataSource)
                ddlThis.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

VERSION 2

```
    public void DataSource(IList source, IList select, string Value = "UId", string Text = "Text")
    {
        ddlThis.DataSource = source;
        ddlThis.DataTextField = Text;
        ddlThis.DataValueField = Value;
        ddlThis.DataBind();

        ddlThisHidden.DataSource = source;
        ddlThisHidden.DataTextField = Text;
        ddlThisHidden.DataValueField = Value;
        ddlThisHidden.DataBind();

        if (select != null)
        {
            ddlOther.DataSource = source.Cast<object>()
                .Select(x => select.Cast<object>().Any(c=> c.GetType().GetProperty(Value).GetValue(source, null).ToString() == x.GetType().GetProperty(Value).GetValue(source, null).ToString()));
            ddlOther.DataTextField = Text;
            ddlOther.DataValueField = Value;
            ddlOther.DataBind();

            foreach (var item in select)
                ddlThis.Items.Remove(item.ToString());
        }
    }
```

VERSION 3 **WORKING!**

```
    public void DataSource(object source, object select, string Value = "UId", string Text = "Text")
    {
        ddlThis.DataSource = source;
        ddlThis.DataTextField = Text;
        ddlThis.DataValueField = Value;
        ddlThis.DataBind();

        ddlThisHidden.DataSource = source;
        ddlThisHidden.DataTextField = Text;
        ddlThisHidden.DataValueField = Value;
        ddlThisHidden.DataBind();

        if (select != null)
        {
            ddlOther.DataSource = ((IEnumerable)source).Cast<dynamic>().ToList().FindAll(x => ((IEnumerable)select).Cast<dynamic>()
                .Any(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(Value).GetValue(c, null) == x.GetType().GetProperty(Value).GetValue(x, null)));

            ddlOther.DataTextField = Text;
            ddlOther.DataValueField = Value;
            ddlOther.DataBind();

            foreach (var item in (dynamic)(ddlOther.DataSource))
                ddlThis.Items.Remove(item.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: you cant. The object itself (of a more derived type than System.Object) must implement IEnumerable in order to go through it. the ddlOther.DataSource to me seems of type system.object. why is "source" as object? This is the problem.

Comment: `DataSource` is an `object`, I think you want to iterate over `ddlOther.Items`

Comment: I am curious to know why you are declaring the values passed as object instead of a specific IList object

Comment: okay I am changing objects to IList, I guess that should work.

Comment: I changed to IList but now  am getting "Object does not match target type." in the "ddlOther.DataSource"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you do not know the exact type of object, but you know for sure that whatever it is, it will have `GetEnumerator` on it (say, because it's a collection or one of your own objects that implements `IEnumerable`) you can stop the compiler from issuing an error by casting to `dynamic`, like this:

```
foreach (var item in (dynamic)(ddlOther.DataSource)) {
    ...
}
```

The trade-of here is that if it turns out that `ddlOther.DataSource` does not have `GetEnumerator`, you will get an error at runtime, rather than a compile-time error.

Comment: yes dynamic solved my problem! just I have last small question
ddlOther.DataSource = ((IEnumerable)source).Cast<dynamic>().ToList().FindAll(x => ((IEnumerable)select).Cast<dynamic>().Any(c => c.UId == x.UId));
in this code I gave "UId" manually but I want to give property name dynamically can I do that? something like .Any(c => c[Value] == x[Value]));

Comment: you can check in the question at version 3. easier to read.

Comment: @Mert Unfortunately, passing property names as string is not possible simply with `dynamic`. You would need to make a method that goes through reflection or through Linq.Expressions to do that.

Comment: yeah I just did it with reflection! thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to check on the IEnumerable interface. It have the feeling underlying correction is more what you want.

```
public void DataSource(object source, object select, string Value = "UId", string Text = "Text")
{
    ddlThis.DataSource = source;
    ddlThis.DataTextField = Text;
    ddlThis.DataValueField = Value;
    ddlThis.DataBind();

    ddlThisHidden.DataSource = source;
    ddlThisHidden.DataTextField = Text;
    ddlThisHidden.DataValueField = Value;
    ddlThisHidden.DataBind();

    if (select != null)
    {
        ddlOther.DataSource = select;
        ddlOther.DataTextField = Text;
        ddlOther.DataValueField = Value;
        ddlOther.DataBind();

        if (select is IEnumerable) //check if the object is a list of objects
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)ddlOther.DataSource)
                ddlThis.Items.Remove(item);
        else //try to remove the single object
            ddlThis.Items.Remove(select)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not going to fix the compilation error since the code that is trying to `foreach` on an `object` is still present.

Comment: Forgot the cast ... sry... edited